# Multidimensional B+ tree

Tags: ds.data-structures, tree

I've got an idea for indexing multidimensional data. I haven't been able to find anything equivalent and am wondering if it is indeed a novel approach.

The idea is a 'stacked' [B+ tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B+_tree) implementation where the leaf nodes contain both the dimension data and a pointer to the next dimension. Each dimension is in itself a B+ tree. It is similar to how [Range Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree) link/point to the next dimension. However, it is different from a Range Tree by using a B+ tree instead of a straight binary search tree.

Also, the elements in each B+ tree layer are unique and are stored with the number of records belonging to each leaf value.

I believe the search complexity would be $(\sum_{i=0}^{d-1} \log _{B} \text{card}(n^{i})) + k$.

Where $\log _{B}$ comes from the branching factor of the B+ tree, $\text{card}(n^{i})$ is the number of unique elements stored for each dimension and $d$ is the number of dimensions stored. $k$ is simply the number of elements returned.

Has anyone written / designed a similar search algorithm before?

Comment: can you implement the multidimensional b tree?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, this is not new; range searching with multilevel B-trees is completely standard.  See, for example, the following surveys:

- Lars Arge.
  [External memory data structures](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~large/Paperpages/dshandbook02.htm).  *Handbook of Massive Data Sets* (James Abello, Panos M. Pardalos, and Mauricio G. C. Resende, eds.), 313-357.  Kluwer Academic Publishers, 2002.  ***See especially sections 5 and 6.***
- Jeffrey Scott Vitter.  [Algorithms and data structures for external memory](http://www.nowpublishers.com/product.aspx?product=TCS&doi=0400000014).
  *Foundations and Trends in Theoretical Computer Science* 2(4): 305–474, 2008. 
  ***See especially section 12.***